# vijava hostsystem update network configuration

Tags: java, networking, system, vmware, host

I'm in need of some help. I have tried several things, but I can't seem to be able to update the network settings from one HostSystem to another HostSystem.

Say I have one HostSystem with the following settings:
HostSystemA - Network Configuration
Standard Switch: virtual_switch1
Virtual Machine Port Groups for virtual_switch1:
    network_1: this network group contains VLAN ID 11
    network_2: this network group contains VLAN ID 20

HostSystemB - Network Configuration
Standard Switch: virtual_switch1
Virtual Machine Port Groups for virtual_switch1:
    network_1: this network group contains VLAN ID 13

I want to take the network configuration settings from HostSystemA and make them the same in HostSystemB. I attempt to do the following as such:

```
// Get host system A
HostSystem hsA = (HostSystem) new InventoryNavigator(rootFolder).searchManagedEntity("HostSystem", "HostSystemA");

// Get host system B
HostSystem hsB = (HostSystem) new InventoryNavigator(rootFolder).searchManagedEntity("HostSystem", "HostSystemB");

// Get the network configuration of host system A
HostNetworkConfig netConfHostA = hsA.getHostNetworkSystem().getNetworkConfig();

// Attempt to update the network configurations of host system B with host system A.
hsB.getHostNetworkSystem().updateNetworkConfig(netConfHostA, "replace");
```

When I execute the code above, I get the following error logs:

```
java.rmi.RemoteException: VI SDK invoke exception:com.vmware.vim25.InvalidArgument
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.WSClient.invoke(WSClient.java:122)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.VimStub.updateNetworkConfig(VimStub.java:2813)
    at com.vmware.vim25.mo.HostNetworkSystem.updateNetworkConfig(testmain.java:161)
    at com.testapp.updateNetFunction(updateNet.java:413)
```

I looked at the API and I think I followed the instructions specified on how to use updateNetworkConfig(), but I could be wrong. That's why I'm reaching out to anyone who can help me out. Thank you.

Link to updateNetworkConfig(): http://pubs.vmware.com/vi30/sdk/ReferenceGuide/vim.host.NetworkSystem.html#updateNetworkConfig

Comment: Do you want to replace the setting of B with A, or merge them? Also it looks like you are using vijava 5.5 beta which has a bug where only RemoteException is being thrown and the actual problem of "InvalidArgument" is not being thrown. I maintain a fork of VIJAVA called YAVIJAVA https://github.com/michaelrice/yavijava which has that bug fixed.

Comment: @Andres Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: @MichaelRice I seem to be experiencing almost or exactly the same problem, but I'm using (a private fork of) version 5.0.1, where I've applied some of the same kinds of fixes with exception wrapping that you've mentioned.  Do you know if there were related issues in earlier versions?